# No internet in terminal

Tags: proxy, internet-connection, ubuntu

Similar questions to this one are all over the net, but I failed to solve my problem even after consulting them :(

I am trying `sudo apt-get update` on a kubuntu 14.04 laptop, and I get a ton of `W: Failed to fetch http://... Something wicked happened resolving ... (-5 - No address associated with hostname)` messages

Also, `ping google.com` gives `ping: unknown host google.com`

I can however connect to the Internet through Firefox...

It is probably related to some proxy issue

I saw suggestions to add statements like `export http_proxy=http://username:pass@proxy_url:port/` to `.bashrc` but I don't know what is my proxy_url exactly.

Checking this website http://aruljohn.com/details.php ,  I can see my port number but I have `Not available` next to `Proxy server`

Please Help!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be related with dns service. Check content of /etc/resolv.conf

In this file you should have something like

```
nameserver xxx.yy.zz.www
nameserver xxx.yy.zz.www
```

If you don't have any lines beginning with nameserver, you should add some there. Use address your provider gave you or use some public, for example Google dns 8.8.8.8.

If you have some entries here, try ping them. If they are not responding add Google dns server on the first line

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

If you are using DHCP, server should provide you  nameservers list and your resolv.conf file should be okay. If it is not, contact your DHCP server administrator.

Comment: Thanks very much for trying to help. This is not the problem however; I was missing the correct proxy_url, and after asking one of my colleagues, now everything works fine. Thanks anyway :)