# Virtualbox - can't use internet on terminal

Tags: terminal, virtual-machine, virtualbox, wget, internet-connection

I have a Linux Mint in a virtualbox VM and I'm able to use Internet through browser. However, when I've tried to use the command `wget www.google.com`, for example, the results is

```
$ wget www.google.com
--2018-12-03 16:46:10--  http://www.google.com/
Resolving www.google.com (www.google.com)... 2800:3f0:4001:810::2004, 
172.217.28.4
Connecting to www.google.com 
(www.google.com)|2800:3f0:4001:810::2004|:80...
```

I've checked the issue [No internet in terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27502921/no-internet-in-terminal) . But, unfortunatelly appears as an specific *proxy* problem and that's not my case.

My VM network config

[image]

I know! Portuguese...

Basicaly, the connection type is set on "Bridge"

And "promiscuous" mode is set as 'Allow everything'.

There is no other adaptor configuration.

Result of command *ifconfig*

```
enp0s3    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:2b:04:c7  
      inet addr:192.168.0.39  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: 2804:14d:c092:4057:6d41:5685:4959:c973/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2804:14d:c092:4057::1005/128 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: fe80::da8c:1d0b:592d:5c90/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:14289 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:9307 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:15589075 (15.5 MB)  TX bytes:938043 (938.0 KB)

 lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:776 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:776 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
      RX bytes:66576 (66.5 KB)  TX bytes:66576 (66.5 KB)
```

Linux Mint network config

[image]

Comment: Maybe problems with IPv6 connectivity? Try passing the `-4` switch to Wget. Also, what is the output of `ping www.google.com`?

Comment: You're right! The problem is IP v6. I've disabled by editing /etc/sysctl.conf and using 'alias' for *wget* and *apt-get* commands. Thanks a lot @darnir !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @darnir, I figured out how to make a 'workaround' to solve this problem! Basicaly, I had to add some 'aliases' for `wget` and `apt-get` in my `.bashrc` file and edit `/etc/sysctl.conf`

Aliases on `~/.bashrc`:

```
# alias for wget force connection through ipv4
alias wget='wget -4 '

# alias for apt-get force connections through ipv4
apt-get='apt-get -o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true
```

Editing on `/etc/sysctl.conf` (Remember this solution is implemented over Linux Mint distro)

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

To restart systcl:

`sudo sysctl -p`

Or, you can use `-w` in `sysctl` command directly. But you'll lost this config as soon as you end the terminal session:

`sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1`

`sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1`

`sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6=1`

**WARNING** this is not a good solution because is not comprehensive to all system. The problem appearently is the algorithms to resolve IPv6 is just too slow to perform properly in VMs( at least in common machines ). If someone has another idea please, post it! :D

Comment: Why is the sysctl method not enough? It will work on all linux machines.

Comment: @darnir - Basicaly, I've tried just changing this vars with sysctl but `wget` still not ignoring ip v6. I had to make an alias passing '-4' option. Have no idea why.